# AI integration to MMORPGS like Trinitycore - Single Player Project

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've started to learn coding a month ago so I'm fairly new to this world and a lot of things are beyond my understanding for now. I've started with python and learned to build small projects and I studied a little bit of lua scripting. But now I'm not sure which direction to go. The reason I started to learn is that I had a dream project for years. I want to code AI player bots and integrate it to my teenager years game called Knight Online which I was playing almost 20 years ago. While I was doing resarch on the internet about integrating AI into a MMORPG, I saw Trinitycore, Azerothcore and Mangos projects. With these projects you can download any World of Warcraft expension you want and you can do leveling, dungeons, raids, bgs, open world pvp, basicly anything you want with bots. So what I want is, to make a road map for myself. What things should I learn ? Where to start ? I don't have false hopes about getting it done right away. Probably it will take me years to learn all that stuff but I'm patient and eager to learn. I just want to invest my time into right things, and I need your guidance for it. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: did you check roadmap.sh/python? it's quite straight forward what to learn next :)

Comment: Hi korzck, thank you for your advice. I did check it after you suggested it but the thing is I don't even know if I should stick with Python. The reason I started with python is that everywhere on the internet it's said that it is the easiest to understand for a beginner. Now I want to learn a suitable language for my goal but I'm not sure which one. As I understand c++ is a good language for it but I'm open all kind of suggestions.